# Display Code in joomla article for learning programing

Tags: joomla3.0

I want to write about C++ programing in my joomla website.
how do i can show c++ code in joomla article ?

like this page:
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/12-comments/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least a couple of extensions in the [Joomla Extensions Directory](https://extensions.joomla.org) that will do this for you:

- [Script Code Highlighter](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/script-code-highlighter) (free)
- [JExtBOX Code Display](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/jextbox-code-display) (paid)

Hint: Search the JED for 'geshi'.